# Jenkins repository location

Tags: maven, jenkins

Which repository location does Jenkins use when building a Maven project? I have chosen `Default (~/.m2/repository)` option while configuring Jenkins but it seems the behavior is a bit different. Though there is this myown.jar present in my local repository i.e. in `/home/username/.m2`, it shows the error that myown.jar is not found. So I have to build a job for this `myown` project, build it and then the error gets solved.

Not only this, when I put the Jenkins script in startup i.e. `/usr/bin/java -jar <warpath>.war`, it downloaded all the dependencies of my projects again while building it, though I had built the configured project 5 times before putting the script in startup !! Isn't it weird behavior? Which repository location does Jenkins use? Or is there something what I might be missing?

Answer (score 17):

actually it depends on configuration of each individual maven project. By default, Jenkins will use the local repository `JENKINS_HOME_DIR/.m2/repository` if you install the maven by ticking the Install automatically checkbox, otherwise it will use the local /home/username/.m2/repository.

however you can change this default location by setting up the settings.xml file in ~/.m2/settings.xml

OR

for global use you can change it from jenkins_home_dir/conf

for example if you install maven by tick Install automatically checkbox

`Step1.` Choose the maven Installation for a particular project in jenkins home directory

```
$ cd Jenkins_home_dir/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/
```

`Step 2.` change the localRepository in settings.xml

The hierarchy for settings.xml is user `.m2` directory and if it could not find that, it will try to find the one in `{maven home}/conf/settings.xml`.

Answer (score 13):

On Windows, when installed and run as a Windows service, this can default to the below.

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\.m2\repository`

`C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.m2\repository`

Comment: how to fix to change C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.m2\repository, as i set Global Configuration, but not changing???

Comment: This was especially strange to track down, because by default find-tools like Agent Ransack won't see this directory -- so I would search my harddrive for an .m2 directory and find nothing.

Comment: @kylexy1357 That is the USERPROFILE home path for SYSTEM account on Windows. `psexec -s cmd.exe` followed by `echo %USERPROFILE%`. `%USERPROFILE%\.m2\repository` is the default Maven local repository location. You can change the user name under which the Jenkins service runs under and that will change the USERPROFILE as well. You can also see it in Jenkins > Configure Jenkins > System Information webpage.

Answer (score 11):

On unix system use `find` tool,

```
[root@ip-172-23-38-167 ~]# sudo find / -name ".m2"
/root/.m2
/var/lib/jenkins/.m2
```

Its under `/var/lib/jenkins` on rhel, (`JENKINS_HOME_DIR` supposed to be `/var/lib/jenkins`)

```
[root@ip-172-23-38-167 ~]# ll /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x.  4 jenkins jenkins   35 Apr 25 00:12 asm
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   38 Apr 23 20:18 backport-util-concurrent
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   17 Apr 25 00:12 ch
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   25 Apr 23 20:17 classworlds
drwxr-xr-x. 23 jenkins jenkins 4096 Apr 25 03:49 com
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   25 Apr 23 20:17 commons-cli
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   27 Apr 23 20:17 commons-codec
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   26 Apr 23 20:17 commons-dbcp
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   24 Apr 23 20:18 commons-io
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   26 Apr 23 20:18 commons-lang
drwxr-xr-x.  4 jenkins jenkins   56 Apr 24 22:45 commons-logging
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   26 Apr 23 20:17 commons-pool
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   27 Apr 25 00:11 eventstream
drwxr-xr-x.  6 jenkins jenkins   63 Apr 25 00:29 io
drwxr-xr-x.  6 jenkins jenkins   69 Apr 25 00:11 javax
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   19 Apr 24 23:09 jline
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   23 Apr 24 23:09 joda-time
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   19 Apr 23 20:17 junit
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   19 Apr 24 22:45 log4j
drwxr-xr-x.  9 jenkins jenkins  104 Apr 25 00:11 net
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   17 Apr 25 00:12 nz
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   18 Apr 25 00:12 ognl
drwxr-xr-x. 34 jenkins jenkins 4096 Apr 25 00:12 org
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   20 Apr 24 23:09 software
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   21 Apr 25 01:47 xmlpull
drwxr-xr-x.  3 jenkins jenkins   22 Apr 25 01:47 xpp3
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be using whatever you have configured in `/home/username/.m2/settings.xml` - remember *username* will be the one effectively executing the jenkins server.  However, if your current maven version has some settings.xml in its /conf directory, that one is prioritary compared to the one in your /home

Once you find (or create) that settings.xml, make it point to wherever you need to have your local repository

Answer (score 1):

By default, Jenkins will use the local repository ~/.m2/repository under the user account used to run Jenkins.

It can be configured to use a private repository for a build, but it sounds as though you haven't configured that.

> When I put the Jenkins script in startup i.e. /usr/bin/java -jar .war, it downloaded all the dependencies of my projects again while building it, though I had built the configured project 5 times before putting the script in startup

From this, it sounds as though your startup script might be running as a different user? Perhaps the `root` user?

Running Jenkins as root would cause it to use a different local repository, i.e. `/root/.m2/repository`. You might check whether there is a Maven repository there, and if so, ensure that Jenkins is never run as root.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [configuration file provider plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin) to manage Maven settings.

The plugin allows configuration files to managed via the Jenkins UI and easily selected for each Maven project build.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, I found the repository location under /var/lib/jenkins/.m2
And I just deleted that one and instead made a link to my existing maven repository ...

Answer (score 1):

0
Unless overriden Jenkins default location for artifacts is: data/jenkins/repository/

If using maven you should add this path when building your project. Like this:

```
'mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/data/jenkins/repository/ clean install'
```

This can also be included in a JenkinsFile config